# LibGDX anti-aliasing makes gray edges

Tags: android, libgdx, textures, gimp

I've small (20x20) circles in my libGDX stage. I have created the texture with GIMP, and for hdpi devices it is (30x30). When I use it in my game, it looks like this, as expected.
[image]

But when I tried linear filtering with following code

```
textureRegion.getTexture().setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear,Texture.TextureFilter.Linear);
```

,The circle has for some reason gray edges:

[image: Circle with linear filtering]

I checked the image in GIMP and it does not have any anti-aliased pixels. The original texture looks same as the first image. Why does it occur and how could I have a smooth circle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If minification is used then border might have to be little bigger. And to avoid gray borders syndrome, transparent border should not be `color(0,0,0,0)` but color of the edge with alpha channel of 0. So white edge picture would use `255,255,255,0` as border color.

[image]

**EDIT**

How I add border with transparent layer using GIMP :

1. Create Canvas with any size(Image Size in GIMP) that you want (File -> New)
2. Draw your Image with transparent outer border/space on a layer.
3. Create new Layer below your Image Layer without space/border with `Colour(255,255,255,0)` so that this layer become invisible.
4. Export your Image.

[image]